# Creating a New List of Sets From a Pre-Existing One

Tags: python

I have the following List of Sets:

```
[{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}]
```

Where each number represents a location. The pairs are locations that are close to one another.

From this I would like to get the List of Sets:

```
[{2,5}, {1,3,5}, {2,6,4}, {3}, {1, 2, 6}, {5,3}]
```

Here, the first set represents all the places close to location 1, the second all the places close to location 2, and so on and so forth. How should I go about turning my initial List of Sets into the Desired List of Sets?

Here is my code as it currently is:

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    data = f.read().splitlines()

set_of_pairs = [{int(n) for n in line.split()} for line in data]
print(set_of_pairs)

6 #Highest number in txt file
1 2
1 5
2 3
2 5
5 6
3 6
3 4
```

Comment: Why are you using *sets* for this?

Comment: Refactor to a graph data structure.  Then your problem is trivial.

Comment: I suppose I could use lists instead, I forgot sets were immutable. Would you recommend I have a list of lists and then turn each list in it into a set afterward?

Comment: Sets are *not* immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are not the right data-structure. Consider a dict of lists (or perhaps a dict of sets, if you only want unique elements)

```
>>> import io
>>> s = """1, 2
... 1, 5
... 2, 3
... 2, 5
... 5, 6
... 3, 6
... 3, 4"""
>>> f = io.StringIO(s)
>>> adjacency = {}
>>> for line in f:
...     a, b = map(int, line.split(','))
...     adjacency.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
...     adjacency.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)
...
>>> adjacency
{1: {2, 5}, 2: {1, 3, 5}, 3: {2, 4, 6}, 4: {3}, 5: {1, 2, 6}, 6: {3, 5}}
>>> [adjacency[i] for i in sorted(adjacency)]
[{2, 5}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {3}, {1, 2, 6}, {3, 5}]
>>>
```

More importantly,you can easily get the items you want:

```
>>> adjacency[2]
{1, 3, 5}
>>> adjacency[1]
{2, 5}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to import io. Is there any way to do this without it?

Comment: @RGPython `io` just lets me use a string like a file-object. Replace that code with your file-handling code.

Comment: @RGPython left out that line. But yeah, just continue from `f` as if `f` were a file you opened normally.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you so much juanpa, you really saved my skin. I'm using a bunch of different files so this will work very well.

Comment: I'm getting a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @RGPython you need to use `line.split()` instead of `line.split(',')`